# Using Django, I want to find all of the published events after today, but only from the nearest month containing events

Tags: django

I have an event object which has `from_date` as a field which represents when the event starts. What I want to do is to find the nearest event, and then find the next upcoming events that are still within the month. Here are the two queries I have so far, is there a way to combine them?

```
today = datetime.date.today()

date = Event.objects.filter(
    status='P', # Published status
    pub_date__lte=today, # Published after today, or today
    from_date__gte=today, # Starting next
).order_by('from_date').only('from_date')[:1][0].from_date

events = Event.objects.filter(
    # Published after today, with a published status, and start today or later
    pub_date__lte=today,
    from_date__gte=today,
    status='P',

    # We're only going to show one month at a time.
    from_date__month=date.month,
    from_date__year=date.year,
)
```

Comment: Why do you want/need to combine them?  It looks pretty straightforward as is -- is there a performance problem?

Comment: I think what you're doing is actually pretty efficient.  Django's query mechanism should collapse those into two SQL queries, one for each filter.  Jamming everything into a single SQL query doesn't always make it more efficient.

Comment: Want to rewrite this response as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're already doing is actually pretty efficient. Django's query mechanism should collapse those into two SQL queries, one for each filter.

Jamming everything into a single SQL query doesn't always make it more efficient.